# Java Web Application with .NET Database

Tags: java, .net, database, web-services, web-applications

I was wondering if I could get some advise/suggestions if anyone has experience with the following situation.

So I want to develop a java web app that "talks" with a database that is already built out in .NET. I have experience coding java web apps in eclipse that talked to MySQL DBs so I don't think the database language is that concerning.

What methods would you go about to implement this? Are there certain programs that are more useful than others? What frameworks should I use? Also, examples that I found on the web seem so dated style wise, are there things I can do to web apps coded in eclipse to give it some pop?

Thank you in advance

Comment: *a database that is already built out in .NET*, so a MS SQL Server database?

Comment: You'll need a [JDBC driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx).

Comment: What does Eclipse have to do with anything?  How would an IDE give web pages "pop"?  Web pages in HTML5 and CSS3, talking to REST web services, would be a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks Duffy I'll do a little more research

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a JDBC driver for MSSQL.

Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Call me [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) on any database.

In these days, from the point of database vendor, they will give us a nice library (driver) to communicate their product from any (widely using) programming language.

`Java` is a big dealing programming language in world wide, so don't worry about database connection as this can be done by a jar featuring [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

So your challenge is JDBC driver to suite and map to required database brand and its version.

You just need to worry to be right plug between the database's version and the JDBC driver library (jar file) version. Don't care on any database of MySQL, [Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC), MSSql or so on.

#### Java app -> JDBC Driver -> Database

Famous database's JDBC drivers;

[MSSql JDBC Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) (What you need one?)
[MySql JDBC Driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
[Oracle JDBC Driver](https://www.progress.com/products/datadirect-connect/jdbc-drivers/data-sources/oracle)